# The limit $x\to 0$ of a fraction, different answers?

Tags: calculus, limits

I can solve the following limit:
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
{
 x(4+x)
}
{
 x(x^2+x(C_1+4)+C_2)
}\\
&=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
{
4+x
}
{
x^2+x(C_1+4)+C_2
}=
\frac{4}{C_2}
\end{align}
So far so good. But *why* is the following method wrong (factoring out $x$ in the numerator and denominator)?
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
{
 x(4+x)
}
{
 x(x^2+x(C_1+4)+C_2)
}\\
&=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
{
 x^2(\frac{4}{x}+1)
}
{
 x^2(x+C_1+4+\frac{C_2}{x})}
\\
&=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
{
 \frac{4}{x}+1
}
{
 x+C_1+4+\frac{C_2}{x}
}\\
&\quad \to
\frac{\frac{4}{0}+1}{0+C_1+4+\frac{C_2}{0}}\\
 &\quad\to  
 \frac{\infty+1}{0+C_1+4+\infty}
\to \frac{\infty}{\infty} \quad \text{indeterminate}
 \end{align}

Comment: You actually wrote $\frac40\ldots$!

Comment: You're right that the result is indeterminate.  But, this doesn't mean that you don't get $\frac{4}{C_2}$.  You don't stop when you get an indeterminate form.  Instead, you have to do some work (such as l'Hopital's rule) to evaluate the limit.

Comment: Apart from the question posed, I think the exercise expects you to find the limits when $C_2\neq 0$ and $C_2=0,C_1\neq-4$ and $C_2=0,C_1=-4$, not just assuming the one case where $C_2$ is non zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke the property that limit of product is the product of limits you need both limits to be finite (and exist obviously).

In the expression
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac
{
 \frac{4}{x}+1
}
{
 x+C_1+4+\frac{C_2}{x}
} $$
neither the limit of numerator nor denominator exist. (your wrote $\infty$ , but remember it could also be that $x\to 0-$)